# Как закрыть одну Activity из другой?

Tags: java, android, activity

Существует необходимость из одной `Activity` закрыть другую. Как это сделать?

Comment: Нет никакой надобности самостоятельно закрывать прошлые активити из текущей, для чего вы это собираетесь делать?

Comment: Необходимость бывает... Есть главное активити, из него открывается активити1, а уже из него активити2. При нажатии, например, на кнопку в активити2 необходимо закрыть оба активити и первое и второе и очутиться в главном

Comment: @sitev_ru читайте про стек активити и флаги запуска активити - http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Для этого нужно очистить стек активити и явно вызвать главную из активити2 - вы начнете "все сначала". Если требуется более сложная логика переходов, то смотрите по ссылке в комментарии выше.

Comment: Запускаете активности2 через `startActivityForResult()`.  В активити2 при нажатии на кнопку выполняете `setResult(OK); finish()`. В активити1 в onActivityResult ловите этот результат и выполняете finish() тоже

Comment: Уточнение из комментария лучше перенести в текст вопроса